# Fixing OuterProjectNode exception when loading some solution projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Loading up one of our solutions in Visual Studio 2019, most of the projects failed to load with the following exception:

> An exception was thrown while initializing part "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.OuterProjectNode"

This exception is shown in the Output window when showing output from Solution.

Choosing reload on the projects shows the following dialog and outputs the same message in the Output window again:
[image: The operation could not be completed]

This is only happening for .NETStandard projects, so I have installed multiple versions of .Net Core and .Net SDKs, thinking I was missing something on this computer.

The only recent change is that this computer has been renamed. The name was changed from olddev-pc to newdev-pc in the past couple days and these solutions haven't been opened since then.

Answer (score 0):

This *appears* to be related to a Windows 10 system rename on the development machine.

Things to try:

- Install missing .NET and .NET Core versions
- Repair current install of Visual Studio
- Uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio

Unfortunately, the reinstall step was the one that fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear all files under the folder ".vs" which will be in root path.
2. Restart Visual Studio 2022.,

This helped me.,